# How to find the co-ordinates of a point in one Cartesian plane with respect to another Cartesian plane?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have one Cartesian co-ordinate system, *C1*, with a point *P(x, y)* on it. I have another Cartesian co-ordinate system, *C2*, placed on top it at a different orientation. How do I find a co-ordinates of *P* with respect to *C2*,given some conditions as follows:-

- Co-ordinates of origin of *C2* with respect to *C1*.
- Any one point's co-ordinates on any one of the axes of *C2* with respect to *C1*.

[Cartesian co-ordinate systems on top of one another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NXYM.jpg)

I want methods and formulae involved in this with their derivations. Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you provide an example? Your picture indicates that the two planes are co-planar just with a different orientation.

Comment: Yes, that's right. They are co-planar, but at different orientations. For example, origin of C2 is (5, 3) with respect to C1. Y-axis of C2 cuts X-axis of C1 at (4, 0). I need to know what a point (3, 6) on the 1st plane(C1) means to the other...

Comment: Please show your work so far. The transformation you describe is a combination of rotation and translation, formulas for which you can easily find for yourself with a web search.

Comment: I'll describe the method I followed to reach my answer. We have the coordinates of the origin and a point on one axis of C2 with respect to C1. Find the equations of the axes. Then, find the distance of the given point from both axes. Then, I used the half plane equations to determine the quadrant of the point. Combining the distances and points, we get the coordinates. But, I feel it is pretty lengthy...